# Probability of no more than X events in Y days (Poisson distribution)

Tags: probability

I have to calculate the probability of no more than 8 events happening in 3 days, given the rate (5). I know I should calculate p(x+y+z)=p(x)*p(y)*p(z), where x+y+z<=8, but as there are quite many combination, I suppose there should be a formula to simplify. Any hints?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution  Under related distribution use sum of Poisson multinomial fact may help or at least give some idea of where to go

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is somewhat tedious, but quite feasible.  We assume that by *rate*, what is meant is *daily* rate. Then the number of events in $3$ days has Poisson distribution, parameter $\lambda=(5)(3)$.

The probability that the number of events is $\le 8$ is
$$e^{-\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^8 \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$